# GRUB loads Windows always in safe mode

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot, grub, safe-mode

I've installed Fedora 31 on a notebook with Windows 10, GRUB shows me different options on boot, and when I choose Windows the system starts but always in safe mode. I have no options to load Windows 10 normally.

This is the boot sequence given by GRUB Customizer:

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root='hd0,gpt1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  B0DE-B937
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root B0DE-B937
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

And this is the result of fdisk -l command:

```
Device           Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1         2048    1026047    1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/sda2      1026048    1107967      81920    40M unknown
/dev/sda3      1107968    1370111     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4      1370112    2906111    1536000   750M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5      2906112 1406771199 1403865088 669,4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6   1933588480 1937344511    3756032   1,8G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7   1937344512 1953523119   16178608   7,7G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda8   1406771200 1408868351    2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9   1408868352 1933588479  524720128 250,2G Linux LVM
```

Can anyone help me setting up GRUB to load Windows correctly? Thanks

Comment: I removed "solved" from the title. The right way to indicate the problem is solved is to accept an answer. You may not be able to accept your own answer so soon; in such case wait few days, then accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved following these steps on windows:

1. Click on **Start**
2. Type `msconfig` (This will bring up the **System Configuration** window)
3. Go to the **Boot** tab
4. If selected, remove the tic from **Safe boot**
5. Click **Apply** and then **OK**
6. Restart your computer